# Execute JavaScript in window.open() generated window

Tags: javascript, window.open

My problems seem to be the following:

I have this code:

```
function openNew(theImage){

    var theHTML = "<!doctype html><html><head><script src='../js/windowScript.js'></script><title>EditWindow</title></head><body><div id='canvasContainer'></div><img id='removeable' src='"+theImage+"'><button id='cropMe'>Crop it!</button></body></html>";
    var editWindow = window.open("","","width=1000 height=800 titlebar=0");


    editWindow.document.write(theHTML);
}
```

which opens a new window with the "theHTML"-Strings content.
And as you can see, it also adds the script "windowScript.js" to the new window.

**windowScript.js:**

```
window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("cropMe").addEventListener("click",removeImg);

    alert("it began");

}

function removeImg(){

    var imgTAG = document.getElementById("removeable");
    var imgURL = imgTAG.getAttribute("src");
    if(imgTAG.parentNode)
        imgTAG.parentNode.removeChild;

}
```

but this script is never executed.
If I check the script via the inspector of chrome, it tells me it's there and it even detects if there are errors in it, but it does not get executed whatsoever.

Is there a workaround to get the script running in the new window, without injecting it via `editWindow.document.write();`
?

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: If it detects there are errors, it's running the script. Have you tried adding explicit `console.log()` calls to it?

Comment: Wow, this is tricky. Even converting the HTML string to a data url and opening a page with that does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** again and actually tested the code.

**windowScript.js**

```
function removeImg(myWindow){
    var imgTAG = myWindow.document.getElementById("removeable");
    var imgURL = imgTAG.getAttribute("src");
    if(imgTAG.parentNode) {
        imgTAG.parentNode.removeChild(imgTAG);
        console.log(imgURL);
    }
    else {
        console.log("fail");
    }
}

function openNew(theImage){

    var theHTML = "<!doctype html><html>" +
                  "<head><title>EditWindow</title></head><body>" +
                  "<div id='canvasContainer'></div><img id='removeable' src='"+theImage+"'>" +
                  "<button id='cropMe'>Crop it!</button></body></html>";

    var editWindow = window.open("","","width=1000 height=800 titlebar=0");

    editWindow.document.write(theHTML);
    editWindow.document.getElementById("cropMe").addEventListener("click",function(){ removeImg(editWindow); });
}
```

**windowtest.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>WindowTest</title>

    <script src="windowScript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:openNew('Capture.PNG')">open window</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's sourced in the head but the script file has the self executing function

Comment: And if it is in the head, how will it find the element?

Comment: I see your point. The script will execute before the elements have loaded and not find the element. It seems more likely that the problem in the original code is that it is writing the html after the page has loaded so the window.onload event in the script will never be triggered. I will update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you provided leaves me with an "**Uncaught ReferenceError: removeImg is not defined**".
But at least I know now, that my code wasn't executed because the window.onload was never called.

Comment: see my updated answer. tested and working. there were a few issues with the code in general but the approach here is to source the functions in a single script on the main doc and reference the new window in the function that removes the image.

Answer (score 0):

you need call to editWindow.document.close();